# VSCode - Create shortcut to insert string

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create a shortcut to insert a specific string into the editor (I am tired of typing "#---------------------..." every single time when separating code blocks).
How do I implement this correctly in VSCode?

Answer (score 3):

I believe File->Preferences->User Snippets is what you're looking for. The example shown looks like:

```
"Print to console": {
"scope": "javascript,typescript",
"prefix": "log",
"body": [
    "console.log('$1');",
    "$2"
],
"description": "Log output to console"
```

Which I read as being able to do what you want. There seem to be files for specific languages or you can start a 'global' snippets file.